# What exactly does the syntax ::~ mean in newly added class in C++ Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++

I have s simple question:

Situation:
When I rightclick Source Files folder and select Add->Class  - C++ class ,
a class is added in a separate file *.cpp and *.h (great! This is exactly what I wanted).

Now: what does the function name

```
classname::~classname(void)
```

exactly does ?

Is it a destructor of that class called "classname" ?

I cannot find explanation of this syntax "::~" on the internet, and so I am asking here. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different things at work here:

- The namespace delimiter operator, `::`
- The destructor, which is a special function that’s *always* called `~classname`.

In your case, the syntax `classname::~classname(void)` simply defines the class’ destructor. The `::` means that what follows belongs to the class called `classname`. And what follows is just the destructor name (see above).

This is the same syntax used for all class member definitions. If your class had a function called `foo` that took an `int` and returned an `int`, then its definition outside the class would look as follows:

```
int classname::foo(int)
```

This is exactly the same as with the destructor (except that the destructor has no return value and takes no arguments).

Comment: Thanx a lot, Konrad  and to all who answered.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's a destructor.

Note that if you're writing your own destructor in production code, you're probably doing something wrong.  The exception would be if you're writing an RAII container, in which case you must also write custom copy constructor and assignment operator, or if you're just trying to learn about destructors.

Comment: Or if you do any form of dynamic memory allocation within the class (and for whatever reason did not/could not use a smart pointer) ... or if the class contains a pointer to a COM object (and the same smart pointer restriction applies).

Comment: Thanx a lot to all who answered.  I hope I will never have to write anything to a destructor in production code :)

Comment: Another example of using a destructor for something useful that does come up fairly frequently is lock classes for thread synchronization.  The constructor opens the lock, the destructor frees it.

Comment: @Zac: You should always use a smart pointer.  If you can't use a standard smart pointer, you should write your own RAII pointer.  A scoped lock (for thread sync) is also RAII.  And in all these cases, you must follow the rule of three.

Comment: @Ben:  Scoped lock objects almost never implement custom copy constructors nor copy-assignment constructors (mainly because their use is to take advantage of construction and destruction semantics to handle thread sync) - unless you are making the object noncopyable (in which case just define them private and never implement them).  I have run into requirements for production projects where the overhead of smart pointers was prohibitive (primarily older embedded systems).  So knowing how to use a destructor properly is always useful.  Stating that you should never write your own is too broad.

Comment: @Zac: I didn't say you should never write your own destructor.  I said you shouldn't except when implementing an RAII class which is responsible for managing the lifetime of one resource.  Furthermore, scoped lock objects absolutely should not let the compiler implicitly define copy constructor and assignment... removing them is still explicitly customizing the behavior.  As for prohibitive overhead of smart pointers, I can only assume you were using the wrong class for the task, because zero-overhead smart pointers are available.

Comment: @Ben:  They are available now; they were not on the system I was forced to use at the time (to give you an idea, this system did not have an STL implementation with its C++ compiler ... it supported C++ syntax only).  But this is way off topic now ...

Answer (score 2):

```
// myclass.h header
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(); // default constructor
 MyClass(const MyClass& mc); // copy constructor
 ~MyClass();  // destructor
};

// myclass.cpp implementation
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass() // implementation of default constructor
{
}

MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass& mc) // implementation of copy constructor
{
}

MyClass::~MyClass() // implementation of destructor
{
}
```

Comment: Even though this is just an example, I'd suggest since it has a copy constructor and destructor, it probably needs a copy assignment operator, `MyClass& MyClass::operator=(const MyClass&)`.

Comment: It should (and would if actually written for anything real).  The rule of 3 applies, but in this case, I left it out as I was focusing on construction and destruction (simply to narrow the scope of the answer to his question).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant

```
classname::~classname(void)
```

Where ~Classname is the destructor method for the class, classname.

:: is the scope operator
~ denotes the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the syntax `classname::~classname() { /*...*/ }` defines the destructor for class `classname`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the destructor.

ClassName::~ClassName() - is how you begin the definition of a destructor in your YourFileName.cpp.

Comment: Thank You, anand.arumug.  And to all for so quick answers! Amazing.